# Why the facebook sdk is not imported

Tags: java, android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I recently downloaded the latest facebook sdk. The step of import is:

1. import facebook sdk
2. Build the sdk , in the bun/res folder there is a facebooksdk.jar ~450kb
3. Copy the jar to desktop
4. In my project , right click properties, in the lib add the external jar and select it include in the build path

The problem is after implemnt the login class like the following:

```
<com.facebook.widget.LoginButton
    android:id="@+id/authButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp" />
```

it can not find the class com.facebook.widget.LoginButton , how to fix it if I would like to make the facebooksdk as jar ? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Facebook SDK is not meant to be added as a jar, you add it as a separate module in your project and depend on it. This link to the SDK Docs (Eclipse): https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started and this link (Android Studio): https://developers.facebook.com/docs/getting-started/facebook-sdk-for-android-using-android-studio/3.0/ do a very god job of explaining how to get up and running. If you follow them you should have no problems.

I don't know what your bun/res directory is but I didn't have any need to build the sdk separately, just depend on the library module you create in your project setting/properties