# How to custom the ui of com.facebook.widget.LoginButton

Tags: android, facebook, android-layout, android-widget

I followed this tutorial ([this](http://www.kpbird.com/2013/03/android-login-using-facebook-sdk-30.html)) to implement facebook login, although it can login and retrieve my email accordingly, the problem I would like to implement a custom login icon.

This is my attempt login xml

```
   <com.facebook.widget.LoginButton
        android:id="@+id/authButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
```

The activity:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    lblEmail = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.t);

    LoginButton authButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.authButton);
    authButton.setOnErrorListener(new OnErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException error) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Error " + error.getMessage());
        }
    });
    // set permission list, Don't foeget to add email
    authButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("basic_info", "email"));
    // session state call back event
    authButton.setSessionStatusCallback(new Session.StatusCallback() {

        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        @Override
        public void call(Session session, SessionState state,
                Exception exception) {

            if (session.isOpened()) {
                Log.i(TAG, "Access Token" + session.getAccessToken());
                Request.executeMeRequestAsync(session,
                        new Request.GraphUserCallback() {
                            @Override
                            public void onCompleted(GraphUser user,
                                    Response response) {
                                if (user != null) {
                                    Log.i(TAG, "User ID " + user.getId());
                                    Log.i(TAG,
                                            "Email "
                                                    + user.asMap().get(
                                                            "email"));
                                    lblEmail.setText(user.asMap()
                                            .get("email").toString());
                                }
                            }
                        });
            }

        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(this, requestCode,
            resultCode, data);
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did this myself not so long ago, its the background resource you need to change, but doing it through XML won't work because it's hard coded in the constructor.

You should extend the LoginButton class and create the two-param constructor as below

```
  public LoginButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
     super(context, attrs);
     this.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.my_own_drawable);
     this.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.my_own_icon, 0, 0, 0);
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Would you mind also look at this facebook sdk problem? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21364257/why-the-facebook-sdk-is-not-imported  Thanks a lot